# Pasar consulta SQL a Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Tengo la siguiente consulta SQL:

```
SELECT
    EFE.FinancialEntityId,
    FE.Name As FinancialEntityName,
    FED.CurrencyId,
    C.Name As CurrencyDesc,
    Count(*) As NumDocuments,
    Sum(FED.CreditCap) As CreditCapSum,
    Sum(FED.AditionalAmount) As AditionalAmountSum,
    Sum(FED.Amount) As Total
FROM [accounting].[EntityFinancialEntity] EFE
INNER JOIN [common].[FinancialEntity] FE ON EFE.FinancialEntityId = FE.FinancialEntityId
INNER JOIN [accounting].[EntityFinancialEntityDet] FED ON EFE.EntityFinancialEntityId = FED.EntityFinancialEntityId
INNER JOIN [common].[Currency] C ON FED.CurrencyId = C.CurrencyId
GROUP BY EFE.FinancialEntityId, FE.Name, FED.CurrencyId, C.Name
```

Deseo pasar esto a una consulta Linq. Mi intento ha sido el siguiente:

```
var q = (from efe in entityFinancialEntities
         join fe in financialEntities on efe.FinancialEntityId equals fe.FinancialEntityId
         join fed in documents on efe.EntityFinancialEntityId equals fed.EntityFinancialEntityId
         join c in currencies on fed.CurrencyId equals c.CurrencyId
         group new {
            fed,
            fed.CreditCap,
            fed.AditionalAmount,
            fed.Amount
         }
         by new {
             efe.EntityFinancialEntityId,
             efe.FinancialEntityId,
             FinancialEntityDesc = fe.Name,
             fed.CurrencyId,
             CurrencyDesc = c.Name
         } into g
         select new EntityFinancialEntityDto {
             FinancialEntityDesc = g.Key.FinancialEntityDesc,
             CurrencyId = g.Key.CurrencyId,
             CurrencyDesc = g.Key.CurrencyDesc,
             NumDocuments = g.Count(),
             CreditCapSum = g.Sum(t => t.fed.CreditCap),
             AditionalAmountSum = g.Sum(t => t.fed.AditionalAmount),
             Total = g.Sum(t => t.fed.Amount)
         }).ToList()
```

Pero me tira el siguiente error:
**La columna 't5.FinancialEntityId' de la lista de selección no es válida, porque no está contenida en una función de agregado ni en la cláusula GROUP BY.**

No comprendo porqué me pide que agrupe esa columna si no la estoy colocando en el select.
Por favor si me orienta, muchas gracias.